# How to draw a partial round rect on a android canvas?

Tags: android, path, android-canvas, draw, android-drawable

I want to draw on a canvas a **round rectangle** fill with color (or bitmap) and with a stroke but **without some selected corners** and also **without the border on some selected sides**. any ideas how i can achieve this ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can split the drawing process into two parts.

1. **draw the fill area**

   when trying to draw a shape that is not support by the standard sdk APIs, Canvas.drawPath method will be a good way to do it.you can just define four variables to represent radiuses of four corners.

   ```
   Path path = new Path();
   Rect drawingRect = {the rect area you want to draw}
   RectF topLeftArcBound = new RectF();
   RectF topRightArcBound = new RectF();
   RectF bottomLeftArcBound = new RectF();
   RectF bottomRightArcBound = new RectF();

   topRightArcBound.set(drawingRect.right - topRightRadius * 2, drawingRect.top, drawingRect.right, drawingRect.top + topRightRadius * 2);
   bottomRightArcBound.set(drawingRect.right - bottomRightRadius * 2, drawingRect.bottom - bottomRightRadius * 2, drawingRect.right, drawingRect.bottom);
   bottomLeftArcBound.set(drawingRect.left, drawingRect.bottom - bottomLeftRadius * 2, drawingRect.left + bottomLeftRadius * 2, drawingRect.bottom);
   topLeftArcBound.set(drawingRect.left, drawingRect.top, drawingRect.left + topLeftRadius * 2, drawingRect.top + topLeftRadius * 2);

   path.reset();

   path.moveTo(drawingRect.left + topLeftRadius, drawingRect.top);

   //draw top horizontal line
   path.lineTo(drawingRect.right - topRightRadius, drawingRect.top);

   //draw top-right corner
   path.arcTo(topRightArcBound, -90, 90);

   //draw right vertical line
   path.lineTo(drawingRect.right, drawingRect.bottom - bottomRightRadius);

   //draw bottom-right corner
   path.arcTo(bottomRightArcBound, 0, 90);

   //draw bottom horizontal line
   path.lineTo(drawingRect.left - bottomLeftRadius, drawingRect.bottom);

   //draw bottom-left corner
   path.arcTo(bottomLeftArcBound, 90, 90);

   //draw left vertical line
   path.lineTo(drawingRect.left, drawingRect.top + topLeftRadius);

   //draw top-left corner
   path.arcTo(topLeftArcBound, 180, 90);

   path.close();

   paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
   canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
   ```

   and you can just set radius to zero for selected corners
2. **draw border**

   border contains eight parts:

   - top-left corner
   - top line
   - top-right corner
   - right line
   - bottom-right corner
   - bottom line
   - bottom-left corner
   - left line

   use a int value to contains selected parts will be a good idea

   ```
   private static final int TOP_LEFT_CORNER = 0x1;
   private static final int TOP_LINE = 0x2;
   private static final int TOP_RIGHT_CORNER = 0x4;
   private static final int RIGHT_LINE = 0x8;
   private static final int BOTTOM_RIGHT_CORNER = 0x10;
   private static final int BOTTOM_LINE = 0x20;
   private static final int BOTTOM_LEFT_CORNER = 0x40;
   private static final int LEFT_LINE = 0x80;

   private int selectedParts = TOP_LEFT_CORNER | TOP_LINE | TOP_RIGHT_CORNER;
   ```

   and now we can draw border based on selectedParts:

   ```
   paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
   if((selectedParts & TOP_LINE) > 0){
       canvas.drawLine(drawingRect.left + topLeftRadius, drawingRect.top, drawingRect.right - topRightRadius, drawingRect.top);
   }

   if((selectedParts & TOP_RIGHT_CORNER) > 0){
       canvas.drawArc(topRightArcBound, -90, 90, false, paint);
   }

   if((selectedParts & RIGHT_LINE) > 0){
       canvas.drawLine(drawingRect.right, drawingRect.top + topRightRadius, drawingRect.right, drawingRect.bottom - bottomRightRadius, paint);
   }

   if((selectedParts & BOTTOM_RIGHT_CORNER) > 0){
       canvas.drawArc(bottomRightArcBound, 0, 90, false, paint);
   }

   if((selectedParts & BOTTOM_LINE) > 0){
       canvas.drawLine(drawingRect.right - bottomRightRadius, drawingRect.bottom. drawingRect.left + bottomLeftRadius, drawingRect.bottom, paint);
   }

   if((selectedParts & BOTTOM_LEFT_CORNER) > 0){
       canvas.drawArc(bottomLeftArcBound, 90, 90, false, paint);
   }

   if((selectedParts & LEFT_LINE) > 0){
       canvas.drawLine(drawingRect.left, drawingRect.bottom - bottomLeftRadius, drawingRect.left, drawingRect.top + topLeftRadius, paint);
   }

   if((selectedParts & TOP_LEFT_CORNER) > 0){
       canvas.drawArc(topLeftArcBound, 180, 90, false, paint);
   }
   ```